# How can I add text on top of slideshow?

Tags: themes

I would like to add text on top of the slide show of the following theme:

http://themeforest.net/item/newcastle-a-woocommerce-powered-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/3887883

The home page is a specific template and writing on the home page template adds text below the slideshow as opposed to above. I would like to have text above and below.

How do you recommend doing this?

Comment: Which text do you want to display on it? You can achieve this using css.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused as to what you are asking. Functionally, all you are required to do is add a DIV with a text block:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="main-nav"> ... </nav>
<div class="introtext">
<your content here>
</div>
<section class="content">
```

Are you asking how to do that as in what file to edit or are you asking how to make it dynamic with something like a custom post type?

Comment: Thanks, I would like to know which file I need to add it too. The home page is a specific template and writing on the home page template adds text below the slideshow as opposed to above. I would like to have text above and below.

Comment: Typically it's in the header.php file. If you do a source-search using something like Notepad++ (or a Mac equivalent) you should be able to string search <section class="content"> and come up with the location pretty fast.